# Login a website using python script redirects at same page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml.html

i am trying to login into a website using python script having the 'form' tag like this in the source code.

```
<form action="trylogin.php" method="post">
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="dpsTlD8zutj35FVWJTIqtUZGX67qQ/vab33hpPyYuaU=" />
<input id="user_username" maxlength="20" name="username" placeholder="Username" size="20" type="text" />
<input id="user_password" name="password" placeholder="Password" size="20" type="password" />
<input class="submit themed_bg themed-dark-hover-background" name="commit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

and i am trying the following python code

```
import requests
import lxml
import lxml.html

s = requests.session()
login = s.get('url')
login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)
hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')
form = {x.attrib["name"]: x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden_inputs}

form['username'] ='user'
form['password'] ='pass'
form['commit'] = 'Login'

response = s.post('url', data=form)
response.ok
response.url
```

s.get() is working fine and response.ok also gives 'true'output but url of response is same as of previous page. it seems like it is redirecting the same page. i can't login from python. What should i do Should i use header arguement in s.post()? how to know it? and i have used

```
form['commit'] = 'Login'
```

since login is in form of input not button, is it correct?

```
<input class="submit themed_bg themed-dark-hover-background" name="commit" type="submit" value="Login" />
```

Comment: `requests.session` for maintaining the session

Comment: session is being maintained in s, as  s=request.session() is used. @ArpitSolanki